# How to attach exported pdf file to Outlook mail using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook, attachment

My code is not finding an exported file to attach to an email.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in the myattachments.add line.

The file name and file directory will always be different based on each client, that's why I have specified a cell specifically for the filename in each quote.

I'm going to copy this Excel file to each client folder and run the code from there.

```
Sub sendremindermail()
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("'Costing'!C1"), Openafterpublish:=True

Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myattachments As Object

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
Set myattachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments

With outlookmailitem
.To = Range("'Costing'!C8")
myattachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & Range("'Costing'!C1") & ".pdf" ' it cant find the pdf in the same directory
'.send
.Display
End With

Set outlookmailitem = Nothing
Set outlookapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA for Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest Outlook VBA does not know Excel VBA's Range.

You could pass the info from Range like this:

```
Sub sendremindermail()

Dim fName As String
Dim pathFileName As String

ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

fName = Range("'Costing'!C8")

'ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("'Costing'!C1"), Openafterpublish:=True
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fName ', Openafterpublish:=True

Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myattachments As Object

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
Set myattachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments

With outlookmailitem
    .To = fName
    pathFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & ".pdf"
    Debug.Print "With fName not Range: " & pathFileName
    myattachments.Add pathFileName
    '.send
    .Display
End With

Set outlookmailitem = Nothing
Set outlookapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Niton thank you for this. I tried your code and got the same error as my original code. it says:

Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)':
Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct.

Comment: Hi there i've figured it out with your help using the pathfilename as string! thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the below code:

```
Sub Mail_Workbook_1()
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
' This example sends the last saved version of the Activeworkbook object .
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hello World!"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Send   
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

For more information, Please refer to this link:

[OfficeTalk: Using the Excel Object Model to Send Workbooks and Ranges through E-Mail with Outlook (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2010/ff458119(v%3Doffice.11))

Comment: Thank you Alina, the challenge here is that you are providing a specific directory i.e. "C:\test.txt" but I need that directory to always look in the current folder, as i'll always be copy-pasting this document into separate client folders to generate quotes